# Same question showing more than once

Tags: discussion, support, bug, asking-questions

The same question was asked by a single user two times, both questions asked in exactly the same time.

It's a **BUG**. Question submitted two times simultaneously.

A single question submitted two times continuously.

> [image]

And following screen shot is user asked questions list page.
Here we can see both two questions.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1370322/nutty-nur?tab=questions

> [image]

Comment: I had same question.... Now got to know this are two different  questions asked having same information .

Comment: Looks like there is no server side validation, or the validation failed. Unless you can reproduce it or see it happening again I don't think it's a big issue.

Comment: Why do you keep bumping this question with minor edits? And why do you think it's necessary to add those additional tags?

Comment: @YiJiang those tags are not unwanted tags. Those are necessary tags only. Adding tags is not a big issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The OP asked the same question twice. [First](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14272300/1369235) and [second](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14272301/1369235). But I can't understand how could he give the same title.

Looking at it's asking time

> [image]   [image]

both questions are asked at the same time (`2013-01-11 05:34:35Z`), and also the body of both questions was same (before editing) that means OP did not ask the question twice (intentionally). It might be a little bug because we can't ask a question with same title.

Comment: Wow, you found both questions..

Comment: @suresh.g: what's difficult in it, just click on two question links:P

Comment: Yes, and first ,second question have different views.

Comment: The body of the question is identical as well. This might be accidental or a bug.

Comment: If the user make two clicks in very short time on the submit there is the possibility to add it two times if the program fail to synchronize the call and see that the question all ready exist - and make the insert on DB again

Comment: @SomnathMuluk first question asked 16 mins ago and second question asked 18 mins ago, but both question asked same time.

Comment: @suresh.g that is actually the 2 minute delay between the OP finding the first question and taking a screen shot and finding the second question and taking a screen shot

Comment: @RhysW yes.. But single user not able to ask two questions at same time.

Comment: @suresh.g like someone pointed out it was a bug, no code is bullet proof, its not an intentional feature or a national security breach / cover up just a little bug ;)

Comment: @RhysW yes....!

Comment: Not necessary, but you could add a unique constraint in the DB question-name row to prevent double inserts, and then just kick back a "We don't like RSIs, so you can single click anywhere on this site!" message.